# Android Studio 0.5.4 new project fails

Tags: android, sdk, path, compilation

I upgraded from AS 0.5.2 to 0.5.4. This required upgrading the SDK. So I did it too. Now it is completely useless. Example:

Starting a new project with default parameters. AS complains that the SDK path for the project and the default Studio SDK are not the same, and asks me to choose one. WHAT? How come 2 paths show up in the first place?

Whatever I then choose fails. IDE internal errors, build errors.

Importing an existing project (from the SDK samples) also fails completely silently. Nothing happens.

Does anyone have similar experience?

Answer (score 0):

Did you setup environment variables? android_home, java_home, gradle_home?

Or on Welcome page to Android Studio go to configure, project defaults, project structure and choose sdk manually

Comment: No. It seems my install was not clean. I wiped it and reinstalled everything and it worked. Not the most elegant way to solve that, but it worked.